# Edit iframe elements with JS

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I’m trying to edit (basically hide) the HTML elements of an `iframe` with jQuery

```
<iframe id="foobar" frameborder="no" class="redirect-frame" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://website.wix.com" seamless></iframe>
```

I’ve tried things like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var f=$('#foobar')
  f.load(function(){
    f.contents().find('#WIX_ADSdesktopWADTop').hide();
    f.contents().find('#WIX_ADSdesktopWADTop').remove();
  })
  alert('test');
}, 5000);

$(window).bind("load", function() {
  $('#WIX_ADSdesktopWADTop').css('display', 'none');
  $('#WIX_ADSdesktopWADTop').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

and also adding the target `CSS` before loading the frame.

I also tried loading the page with jQuery (not `iFrame`):

```
$("#test").html('<object id="foobar" class="redirect-frame" data="http://website.wix.com">');
```

But no luck. The only thing that runs is the `alert('test');`

Any ideas? My guess is it’s not working because the page doesn’t come from the same origin? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news, the iFrame block by default the cross origin injection, you should try to appendChild on it, but I don't know if it will work.